# Noun that describes a person who learns from any experience

Tags: single-word-requests

What word in English describes a quality in person that allows him to learn from any kind of experience? Be this a hobby, homework, or any kind of activity. More specifically, I’m interested how would we call a person who can take advantage from various experiences to learn take new insight and learn something new.

Comment: A self-learner?

Comment: A self-learner emphasizes another point, the fact that you're able to grasp subjects on your own, without others' help. The word I'm seeking for, if such a words exists, focuses on the aspects described in the question more.

Comment: Are you talking about someone who picks things up quicker than the Average Joe? or someone who primarily learns from experiences rather than passive studying?

Comment: I suppose my comment was short-hand for saying, I don't think such a word exists but the closest I immediately think of is *self-learner* because the ability to "grasp subjects on your own without others' help" is necessary in order to "learn from any kind of experience."

Comment: I have in mind someone who primarily learns from experiences. Of course he can learn from passive studying too, it's inclusive, but I want the word to demonstrate the first part more.

Comment: What about the adjective "quick-witted" (*quick in perception and understanding, mentally alert*) ?

Comment: Hmm, it does include what I'm trying to convey, but only indirectly. I hope a  more direct, concise word should exist too.

Comment: "Wise" works fairly well.

Comment: Astute? Precocious?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly **Experiential Learner** will work for you.

> #### Experiential Learning
>
> - The process of learning through experience, and is more specifically defined as "learning through reflection on doing"

I have come across the phrase *Experiential Learning* being used most recently at colleges to describe "the process through which students develop knowledge, skills, and values from direct experiences outside a traditional academic setting" ([UCDenver](http://www.ucdenver.edu/life/services/ExperientialLearning/about/Pages/WhatisExperientialLearning.aspx)).

In lieu of formal definitions, I give you additional linked examples of use:

> 1. [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/jasonma/2015/05/15/how-unconventional-experiential-learning-is-reshaping-higher-education/#4f2873503743)
> 2. [UCF](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=20&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj78fG124PRAhUB2SYKHRb3D8cQFgh_MBM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.explearning.ucf.edu%2F&usg=AFQjCNFR0hluT8PgctiFXHUvZryyhB0qcA&sig2=I7G9H1cKjRNtvQiGf3duaQ)
> 3. [UCDavis](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=17&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj78fG124PRAhUB2SYKHRb3D8cQFghuMBA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.experientiallearning.ucdavis.edu%2Fwhy-el.shtml&usg=AFQjCNG1FqLb0kfbUOOCVwF1iNJxI_pMnA&sig2=xGIU6Oyr2F3OVRmm0nh5bw)
> 4. [UT-Austin](https://facultyinnovate.utexas.edu/teaching/strategies/overview/experiential-learning)

Answer (score 0):

An autodidact is "a person who has learned a subject without the benefit of a teacher or formal education; a self-taught person." (Dictionary.com) I have also heard "sponge" used similarly: He sponges up information. She's a data sponge.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if someone learns from experience, we can say he is guided by experience.

If so, consider **empiric**.

One who is guided by practical experience rather than precepts or theory. [(TFT)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/empiric)

Or assimilator as a noun, but here is an example from [Dictionary.come](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/assimilator) as a verb:

> He assimilated many new experiences on his European trip.

So, how about experience-assimilator.